# extract names of list entries that are NA

Tags: r, list

I have a list as follows:

```
mtlist = as.list(mtcars)
mtlist[[2]] = NA
mtlist[[5]] = NA
```

What's the most concise way to extract the names of the list elements which are NA?

I came up with the solution below. Yet I wonder if there are other better options. Especially `all(is.na(x))` seems error prone to me.

```
names(which(sapply(mtlist, function (x) all(is.na(x)))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `is.na()` function to check which of the elements of list are NA and extract their names using `names()` function.

```
names(mtlist)[is.na(mtlist)]
# [1] "cyl"  "drat"
```

Comment: so obvious, I didn't think of that.

Comment: happens!! We think way too much sometimes and the solution is very simple.